# View class tree in visual studio 2010 for file without a project

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, class

Is there a possibility in Visual Studio 2010 to view a class tree for a CPP-file without loading it into the current project?

I want to open a couple (header file, source file) and be able to browse through all the methods of all the contained classes. I have searched here on the forum as well as on the Internet, but could not find anything.

Are there similar tools from third-party vendors?

Comment: Sorry, but no. VS won't do much of anything with your code unless it's part of a project.

Comment: @JerryCoffin that's a pity. If you made your comment an answer, I would accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At least as far as I know, VS won't do much of anything with your code unless it's part of a project.

Depending on exactly what you want, there are quite a few similar tools. The most common is probably doxygen.

Many (most?) UML tools can also reverse engineer (UML) class diagrams from source code, and quite a few support "round-tripping" (ability generate a class diagram from source code, manipulate the UML, then generate new code matching the edited UML).

I should probably also point out, however, that these tools aren't necessary very popular (in fact, some people really hate them) and it's probably a pretty rare case where generating class diagrams with them is going to be any quicker or easier than creating a project file so you can do it inside of VS. Most of them have quite a few features that VS does, so they may be worthwhile if you want to do things VS doesn't support. If, however, you're happy with the results VS produces, using VS and creating a project file is probably the easiest way to get it.

Comment: This sounds like a business opportunity! Thanks for your reply!